# Exact sentence search in solr drupal 7

Tags: php, search, solr, drupal-7

I wanted to know if there is a way in solr config to have an exact sentence match search in apache Solr in the Drupal 7 site.

**example**: While I am searching

Search for “Could my baby have an allergy?”

The expectation of Search result - “Could my baby have an allergy?”

Current behavior - “Could” + “my” + “baby” + “have” + “an” + “allergy?”

The Result will show all the above word combinations of search results.

But I need only an exact search for "Could my baby have an allergy?".

Thanks,

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: A  `string` field will give only exact hits (including case).

Comment: As Mats mentioned, you are probably using a "text" field for your search and hence getting the behavior that you described. Using a "string" field will address this but keep in mind that then the search will really need to be exact, including casing and punctuation.